# Creating a Wifi peer to peer connection between Android and PC

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, wifi

I have a question about the p2p functionality of Android OS (4.x and higher). I have a PC program that makes use of the Boost C++ library that can function as a server or as a client. Now i have a Android app that has a server using Java sockets. This program need a accesspoint to connect to each other.

I'm looking for a way to connect the Android server and the PC client program without a accesspoint. After looking around i found out that Android has a p2p library. 
[Android P2P](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)
As a read it you can only connect two Android devices with each other, my question is if it is possible to use this library to connect the Android device to the PC using wifi p2p? Or if there is a other possiblity? All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roy, have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct
WiFi P2P is now called WiFi Direct, and it is indeed possible to connect two devices as long as *one* of the devices supports it.  So Android device in P2P mode and a PC without any special configuraiton should work fine.  However, the PC can (probably) only connect to one access point at a time, from its perspective the Android device is the access point, it would have to disconnect from its usual access point to connect to the Android device.

Also check out SoftAP.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Is there a example or tutorial how to work with Wifi-direct in Android that you no of? I found a example on the Android development site but found this not clear. Do you know a good example or tutorial?