# Is it possible to have an app interact with a PC over one's own wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifip2p

I'm new to Android development, and one of my app's function (at least on paper) would be interacting with a PC of choice and saving images. I came across [Wifi Peer-to-Peer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html), and it appears that I might be able to do that but there is no official documentation on it.

I also came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723868/creating-a-wifi-peer-to-peer-connection-between-android-and-pc) which seems to imply that I may be able to do so, but I would like some verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can use TCP. So you can do what you like, you just need the internet permission. Ad hoc networks are also possible, but I would not use them better use a given infrastructure.

Comment: Okay, thanks. To be honest, I am not entirely sure what TCP exactly is, and so I googled it and it brought me to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: TCP is a stateful network protocol. Yeah you can use sockets for that, but I guess there are also some more higher level libraries which would better work for you. Do you have any idea how you would like to communicate with the pc?

Comment: Well, my basic goal is to be able to take picture (or pictures) and save it on the computer through wifi. So I just need permission (or the ability) to save data on the computer.

Comment: I see, well network programming can be tricky. Your goal is reachable I implemented that too. I guess the question is answered so far here so please accept it. Do some reseach for network/socket programming and try to implementing that if you get stuck ask another question with your current knowlage state. Good luck!